# Need Python program that which can read the redshift data, and push the same data in to salesforce on the daily basis

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, salesforce

Is there any way to load data from redshift to salesforce using python,please provide some sample code am new to python scripts.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, Redshift is mostly compatible with PostgreSQL, so you can use any of the [PostgreSQL](http://initd.org/psycopg/) clients for Python to query Redshift databases from Python.

Now to saleForce, 
*"Simple Salesforce is a basic [Salesforce.com REST API](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simple-salesforce) client. The goal is to provide a very low-level interface to the API, returning an ordered dictionary of the API JSON response"*

your turn now...

Comment: can you please provide any python source code,am not a developer for python,am still learning python..Thanks for the quick response